# I would like to change hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp

I just received an old XP desktop computer that I am going to upgrade. If I take the old hard drive out and put a new one in will the systems user accounts, operating system etc, be saved or will everything be gone and the system like brand new? I ask cause I don't want anything that is currently on the hard drive and just want a new reliable hard drive.

Comment: Everything, including Windows, is stored on the hard disk. Removing a hard disk = removing everything.

Comment: @gronostaj: BIOS is not removed.

Comment: @ElsdenIep, you're right.

Answer (score 4):

The hard drive is where the OS, user accounts, programs, and data is stored. If you remove it. All of that is no longer accessible.

Unless you transfer data, the new hard drive will be blank. There will be no OS, no user accounts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer has a single hard-drive and you remove or replace it the computer will have **none** of the previous data. A new blank hard-disk will not have **any** operating system, so it will not be *like new* if you expect there to be an operating system.

Answer (score -3):

If you install a new HDD, probably the only user account that will be available afterwards, is the BIOS account.

Comment: What do you mean by 'BIOS account'?